# 変数にhtmlタグが含まれているデータをview.bladeで出力したい

Tags: php, html, laravel

#### 状況

（そもそもこの仕様が好ましくないのは承知ですが）DBに`<font ~>あいうえお</font>`のような形でhtmlタグが入ったデータがあります。ほしい文字列`かきくけこ`のみのデータもあります。

以下の二通りが存在します。

1. `$a = <font ~>あいうえお</font>`
2. `$a = かきくけこ`

#### 期待する結果

bladeファイルで後者の変数だと`<div ~>{{ $a }}</div>`で問題ないですが、前者だとhtmlタグが文字列として出力されるので、htmlタグとして認識して欲しい。

**環境**
PHP 7.x
Laravel
Windows 10

参考、実装方法をご存知の方、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{!! $a !!}
この書き方だとhtmlタグがhtmlタグとして認識し、$aを文字列としてではなく変数として認識してくれました。

{!! $a !!}
で実装できました。